# Python websocket connection to a Vivotek IB9387-HT-A

Tags: python, libwebsockets

I need to set up a websocket connection to a Vivotek IB9387-HT-A web camera.

The javascript connection works. When connecting via python I get the response:

```
"websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 401"
```

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def websocket_example():
    uri = "ws://root:password@192.168.94.221:80/ws/vca?data=meta,event"

    try:
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
            # Send a message to the server
            message_to_send = "Hello, WebSocket!"
            await websocket.send(message_to_send)
            print(f"Sent: {message_to_send}")

            # Receive a message from the server
            received_message = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"Received: {received_message}")

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
        print(f"Connection closed: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websocket_example())
```